# How can I learn all that CompizConfig has to offer for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? (Gnome)

Tags: settings

I have installed CompizConfig on my system. If there is any detailed usage video or may be tutorial on all basic aspects of ConpizConfig for Ubuntu 20.04 TLS, it would be marvellous. This application looks very sophisticated and I do not want to damage my system settings so I am looking for some good tutorials for this. If anyone can guide me, I will be very grateful. Thank you friends. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal experience is usually better.

To get limited experience you have to install GNOME Flashback session by `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback` and then select *GNOME FlashBack (Compiz)* session on the login screen.

To get all Compiz features - you have to:

1. install Ubuntu MATE desktop by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`
2. install Compiz for MATE by `sudo apt-get install compiz-mate compiz-plugins-extra`
3. login to the MATE desktop session
4. activate Compiz usage in MATE Tweak (use Windows → Window Manager).

All possible Compiz plugins may be then configured using CompizConfig Settings Manager. Install it with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` and then launch with `ccsm` or from menu.

Comment: Thanks friend. I must have written, I have Gnome and I have already installed it. But I do not know how to use it. If I do things, try things in it, I am afraid that it will damage something in my desktop which I want to avoid as new user. So I am looking for videos, guides and tutorials on it. I edited the question now. Thanks. :)

Comment: Above answer may be implemented in the Virtual Machine (Virtual Box or similar) to avoid damage.